# Best practice for duplicate identical on database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a new database which has more than 30 tables with standard values, for example, one of them stores the vehicles information, one of those fields is **fuel**, this will always be an option of "Gasoline" or "Diesel".

The problem here is that this database will have more than 50,000 vehicles, so if 50% of them are Gasoline, I'll have 25,000 rows repeating the same "Gasoline" value.

Considering that "Gasoline" has 8 bytes and "Diesel" 6 bytes.
If I store the value on each row as a `varchar(8)` with the fuel name on it the total of 50,000 records would come at 200KB + 150KB = 350KB. If I store it as a `char(1)` and specify that "Gasoline" = 1 and "Diesel" = 2, the total size would be reduced to 50KB.

Which would be the best to do in this situation?

1. Creating a "list_fuel_names" table and creating a relationship between the tables;
2. Processing the value on the server like `if fuel=1 echo "Gasoline" else if fuel=2 echo "Diesel"`
3. Saving the fuel name in the field with the `varchar(8)`

Any other options are open for discussion and appreciated.
Best regards.

**Edit 1:** I also have a "Persons" table where the gender is stored with a `char(1)` value it I don't have any "list_gender" table, so I'll decode that in the back-end code.

**Edit 2:** As there are more than 30 tables with the same issue, I would have to create more than 30 tables just to list values, would this be efficient? I'm asking because at the end I could be using more space that I would if I was writing the value in a `varchar` column.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Also, some systems have enumerated types, such as MySQL's `enum('Gasoline','Diesel')` which is stored as an integer, and displayed as text...

Comment: Option 1 is a generally accepted design for a problem like that.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I'm using the Microsoft's RDBMS SQL Server

Comment: If you are allowing a single vehicle to be a Gasoline, Diesel, or both, then you need a separate table to avoid entering the same Vehicle twice in your Vehicle table.

Comment: You can have `FuelType`, `Vehicle` and `VehicleFuelType<FK vechicleId, FK fuelTypeId>` tables

Comment: The advantage of using a separate (reference) table is when you need to add a new fuel type, such as biodiesel, alcohol, hydrogen, electricity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex, subtle issue. It boils down to "what do you want to optimize for?".

Firstly, I wouldn't optimize for disk space except in *very* rare circumstances. You've spent more money typing this question than it would cost to store 350KB.

You have a few options.

"Store the attributes as strings" is simplest, and very expressive - you can just ask "find all diesel cars" etc. The downside is that you need a mechanism to validate those strings - they must be either diesel or petrol, no typos. This logic gets spread across your application, and changing it (hello, electric cars!) can be messy.

"Store the attributes as foreign key relationships" avoids the typo problem, and is generally considered best practice. You have a "fuel_types" table, and your "vehicle" table has a column called fuel_type, with a foreign key to fuel_types; the database makes sure only valid entries are accepted. If you remove a fuel type, the database can make sure you have no orphaned items. If you need to introduce more logic around fuel type, e.g. "tax band", or "supplied_by", you can extend your fuel_types table. The downside is that you have more code to write for database access - more joins when selecting all vehicles.

"Store the attribute as an enumeration" avoids some of the problems of strings - the enum makes sure you only store valid options, and you can extend the enum when new fuel types become available. Someone reading your schema will see immediately that there are only a limited number of options. If you don't anticipate any additional logic around fuel type, this is a decent solution.

"Store the attribute as a magic string" is a pretty horrible solution - you've got a lot of code to maintain, lots of places where you need to make sure that "D" = diesel, and someone reading your schema would have no idea this is happening.

Comment: You can have a foreign key and still use `varchar(8)` though, you just have a single column lookup table. This prevents incorrect data being inserted